# ASP.NET Web Application: connected services is empty

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, connected-services

I have a asp.net web application (.NET Framework 4.7.2) that I would like to add a connected service to (in Visual Studio 2019 or 2022), but when I go to add the connected service (right click on project > Add > Connected Service) the Connected Services page is blank.

Note: I can add a connected service to a .NET Framework console application, but not a Web Application.

Is this something that is not available to web applications?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can check if VS is installed correctly. You can try to install VS again.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT thanks for the suggestion, I did try that. I installed VS 2022 to see if that was the issue, but it still does not work.  Other developers I work with are seeing the same thing.